# Why is "for" used in "for me" in standup meetings?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

In standup meetings where each attendee tells about what they did yesterday in turn, people always start with "For me", for example, "For me, yesterday I finished my task" or "For me, yesterday I was out of the office". What is the usage of "for" in "for me" here? Is it short for "As for"? I rarely see this usage in other occasions.

Comment: Yes, in that context, "for me" means "as for me", but it's somewhat less formal.

Comment: Business culture. Your coworkers have gotten used to saying it that way. Just as they have gotten used to the horror of a "standup meeting."

Comment: @Dan haha I'm so fed up with this "recall what you did yesterday" thing